# How to dynamically change a parameter of a javascript call from the href attribute of an element

Tags: javascript, jquery, html

Is there a way to dynamically change what parameters are passed to a javascript function from an html element? For instance, say I have the following:

```
<a id="myElement" href="javascript:myFunction('myParam');">Click me!</a>
```

How can I change 'myParam' to another parameter, say 'myParam2'? An answer using either javascript or jquery is fine with me. For simplicity's sake, feel free to suppose I can find this element by document.getElementById('myElement') or some other means.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

What I would do instead is bind a click handler and use `this` to figure out which was clicked.

```
$('#myElement').click(function () {
    console.log($(this).text()); // Should dump "Click me!" to the console.
});
```

You could then add attributes to your links, such as `data-someParam="my value"` and access them with `.attr()`.

Comment: You can also access `data-*` attributed with `.data()` however that function makes its best attempt to convert the value to the js type, so using it depends on what kind of values youre dealing - 0 padded numbers are an obvious point of confusion sometimes

Comment: @prodigitalson, Good to know!  I didn't know such a method existed.

Comment: I actually already have a handler like that, which might work well. However, I have a slight problem because I don't know the parameters ahead of time (they are passed in from a Python backend through jinja2). I guess I could store them in hidden fields, and access those fields through the handler...? Unless there is a better way.

Comment: @TonyWickham, Either way, set the values as attributes on the element.  It doesn't matter if you do that client-side or server-side.

Comment: Keep in mind that accessing data-* with data() will force the name to be lowercase, so you would access data-somParam with data("someparam") not data("someParam")!

Answer (score 3):

To accomplish what you want you can do something like this

```
var ChangeParam = function(el,newParam) {
    //make sure things aren't broken:
    if(typeof el !== 'undefined' && el.href && typeof newParam !== 'undefined') {
        var parta = el.href.split('(')[0] + '('; //get the stuff before the param
        var partb = ')' + el.href.split(')')[1]; //get the stuff after the param
        el.href = parta + '"' + newParam + '"' + partb; //put it all together
    } else { return false; }
}

ChangeParam(document.getElementById('myElement'),'meow');
```

### example: http://jsfiddle.net/q7R9B/2/

---

**Edit:** I made it a pretty function, hooray!

Comment: This looks like it will do what I want. However, I believe it will fail if a parameter has a ' in it (because it will be split). Like if my parameter was 'I say \'tomato\' you say \'tomato\'', it will be split into multiple parameters, right?

Comment: +1 for answering what I initially asked. I wish I could accept two answers, but I had to go with Brad's since it seems more stable/better practice.

Comment: Also, just as a heads up for future readers, this will only work if you have one parameter (like in my question). If you have multiple, you may want to consider another answer.

Comment: @TonyWickham I may just go through and add support for multiple parameters haha and yeah fair enough :)

Answer (score 1):

Should be able to use this as well:

```
document.getElementById('myElement').href = "javascript:myFunction('myParam2');"
```

Cheers, LC